# How to set a multicharacter record separator RS in GNU awk so it encompasses the new lines?

Tags: regex, awk

I am using GNU Awk 4.1.3. I want to process this file:

```
$$$$
1
1
$$$$
2
2
$$$$
3
3
$$$$
1
clave
2
$$$$
5
5
$$$$
```

And print the block of lines that go between "$$$$" and the next "$$$$" when that given block contains the text "clave" in it. That is, with the given example I want this output:

```
1
clave
2
```

My solution is to set the [record separator `RS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Multiple-Line) to the string "$$$$". Since it is a special character, I need to escape it, so it ends up being like `RS='\\$\\$\\$\\$'`:

```
awk -v RS='\\$\\$\\$\\$' '/clave/' file
```

The problem with this is that the result contains a new line before and after the block:

```
$ awk -v RS='\\$\\$\\$\\$' '/clave/' file

1
clave
2
```

This is because there is a new line between the end of "$$$$" and "1", and there is also a new line between "2" and the next "$$$$".

To avoid this, I am adding the new line on both ends of the record separator, so it becomes `RS='\n\$\$\$\$\n'`. It works well:

```sh
$ awk -v RS='\n\\$\\$\\$\\$\n' '/clave/' file
#            ^^^           ^^
1
clave
2
```

However, this becomes quite complex and I am wondering if including the new line in the record separator may have some side effects that I am not aware of.

For this, I wonder: how can I set the record separator so it encompasses the new lines? Is my approach valid or should I go for other options because my approach has some drawbacks?

Comment: A very good question, noticing your presence after long time @fedorqui

Comment: Thanks a lot, @anubhava, it is great to see you good people are still around!

Comment: The presented approach has some drawbacks. **(1)** your first record will contain the line `$$$$`, the last record _might_ end with `$$$$` if your file does not end with a newline. The solution presented by @anubhava works. You might even consider to convert it to `\n*\$\$\$\$\n*` if you want to include empty lines as an RS.

Comment: @kvantour excellent, this is the insight I was looking for. I had done some tests but hadn't found this case. Many thanks.

Comment: Take into account that, when using the `RS` defined by @anubhava, your first record (`FNR==1`) will be empty if your file starts with an `RS`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be matching on the newline before and after the 4 `$`s as THAT is the real separator (a string of 4 `$`s on a line of it's own), anything else could fail if 4 `$`s appeared in your data. The first sting of `$`s won't have a newline before it of course, it'll match the start-of-string indicator (`^`) instead, so you need to use:

```
$ awk -v RS='(^|\n)[$]{4}\n' '/clave/' file
1
clave
2
```

I find `[$]` easier to read than `\\$`, YMMV.

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot Ed. Time passes and you are always the one who sheds more light in the Awk field

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a newline before and after because there is a new line before and after `$$$$` in your file and by setting `RS` to `$$$$` you are leaving those line breaks in record.

Change your `RS` to include a newline or start before and a newline or end afterwards, so that a record will be without those line breaks:

```sh
awk -v RS='(^|\n)\\${4}(\n|$)' '/clave/' fike

1
clave
2
```

Also note that you can use fix length quantifier `\\${4}` instead of `\\$\\$\\$\\$`.

Comment: Indeed, if you force having `\n[$][$][$][$]\n` as `RS`, the example file of the `OP` will not pick up the first line as record and the last line if the file does not end with a newline. The proposed solution here avoids that problem. The side-effect of setting this `RS` is that in most cases, the first record is empty.

Comment: That would fail if `$$$$` appeared mid-line in a record, e.g. `foo$$$$bar`.

Comment: Well, now it looks [very familiar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64895688/1745001) :-). You don;t need `(\n|$)` at the end, just `\n`, since text files always end in `\n`.

Comment: Ah I just noticed your answer and ++ to you. Will leave `(\n|$)` for some an edge case when file doesn't end with newline.